# Enforce const ref on std::function argument

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reference, lambda, std-function

I have a function that takes a std::function parameter. I want the std::function to have a bool& argument :

```
void function(std::function<bool(bool&)> lambda);
```

but the ref constraint is not enforced, I can have :

```
auto lambda = [](bool canceled) ->bool{};
```

or

```
auto lambda = [](bool& canceled) ->bool{};
```

Compiler is MSVC 2010.

**N. B.**

The first example used a const ref for the bool, because the bool variable is changed in another thread and I need to keep track of its value that's for the ref. And I can't modify it in the lambda, hence the const.

Comment: for `bool`, why do you need `const` reference? It is better to make the parameter just `bool`. No `const`, no reference.

Comment: Also, how do you know the constraint is not enforced?

Comment: Why would you ever want to pass a bool value by ref ? (Not to mention const ref, they are both nonsense, you are even faster simply giving it it's own copy and then returning whatever state you need.)

Comment: You'd pass a bool by ref if you need to modify it. By const ref is a bit silly though, as you might as well just pass it by value seeing as how it'll be the same size. Or smaller.

Comment: The bool is changed in another thread.

Comment: Fixed the `consts` in your text. Maybe it makes more sense now.

Comment: It's not a question about performance.

Comment: The const should stay, cause the bool is changed in another thread (and I can't modify it the lambda) and I need to keep track of its value. But that makes the example less simple, I agree.

Comment: Nawaz, I know that the constraint is not enforced because the compiler accepts the two lambdas, not just the second.

Comment: `std::function` is designed to be a wrapper that accepts, in your case, a `const bool&`, and calls anything that's callable with a `const bool&`. A `bool(const bool)` function *is* callable with a `const bool&` argument. Shouldn't you just treat this as a case of user error, where user is the person who wrote the lambda function? It's no different than using `bool f(const bool x) { ... } bool g(const bool &x) { return f(x); }` and using `g`.

Comment: hv, I wanted the compiler to check for the signature. The user will surely once in a while pass a bool without a ref and will not have the expected behavior.  So there's no way to force a reference parameter in a std::function ?

Comment: Maybe you could have it take a pointer instead of a reference, or wrap the reference inside a class and have it take that.

Comment: I thought about using a pointer, but I hoped I could use a ref. Wrapping the ref or the pointer inside a class is a nice work around, thanks.